# Get application list from Azure AD with same user access

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to create a dashboard. Azure AD is used to authenticate the user and i already implemented that. Now my task is to display the icons in the dashboard according to access. for eg in my organization, there are 3 other applications, A, B and C. User has access to application A and B but not C, so after login, the user can see Applications A and B as icons but not C. On click of A or B, will allow user to access without any sign in again. Any pointer would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you will probably find it's simpler to use the existing Access Panel from Azure AD (https://myapps.microsoft.com), which already displays the apps the user has access to.

That said, if you have a compelling reason to re-build this yourself, you can list a user's app role assignments (apps that the user has been assigned to) using the Microsoft Graph API or the Azure AD Graph API. For example, using the Microsoft Graph, the following request will list the apps the signed-in user is assigned to:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/appRoleAssignments
```

In the resulting list of app role assignments, the `resourceId` attribute will identify a ServicePrincipal object. You can then retrieve the ServicePrincipal object and retrieve (for example) the `homepage` property (for building your link):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{id}
```

(Note: The equivalent requests using Azure AD Graph are below:)

- `GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/me/appRoleAssignments`
- `https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/servicePrincipals/{id}`